# XML generate from SQL query

Tags: xml, xslt

I have SQL query with output:
1. @now_data - it is date and time
2. @cbank - list od bank

I create XSL:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method = "text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each select="ROOT">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="RECORDSET1"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="RECORDSET1">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="RECORD" mode="r1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RECORDSET1">
<!-- Part 1 start-->
   <xsl:text>&#60;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&#62;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
   <xsl:text>&#60;Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"&#62;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
<!-- Part 1 end-->  
   
   <!-- Part 2 start-->
   <xsl:text>&#60;CreDtTm&#62;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="@now_data"/>
   <xsl:text>&#60;/CreDtTm&#62;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
   <!-- Part 2  end-->
  <!-- Part 4 start-->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="RECORD" mode="r1"/>
   <xsl:text>&#60;/CstmrCdtTrfInitn&#62;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
   <xsl:text>&#60;/Document&#62;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Part 4  end-->
<xsl:template match="RECORD" mode="r1">
<!-- Part 3  start-->
      <xsl:text>&#60;ClrSysMmbId&#62;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
        <xsl:text>&#60;MmbId&#62;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@cbank"/><xsl:text>&#60;/MmbId&#62;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
      <xsl:text>&#60;/ClrSysMmbId&#62;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
  <!-- Part 3  end-->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output should be like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
<CreDtTm></CreDtTm>
<ClrSysMmbId>
<MmbId>10501445</MmbId>
</ClrSysMmbId>
<ClrSysMmbId>
<MmbId>10501445</MmbId>
</ClrSysMmbId>
<ClrSysMmbId>
<MmbId>12402089</MmbId>
</ClrSysMmbId>
</CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

Part with bank name working perfect but I have problem with CreDtTm - is empty. When I put this part in loop (Part 3), CreDtTm has date and work correctly.

What should I change to have date at ?

Comment: SQL query is not an actual format until it is exported to flatfile (txt, csv, etc.). Plus, xslt works on xml formats. Are you outputting query into xml?

Comment: Yes, sql query is send to xml format.

Comment: Please show input XML like you did desired results. We cannot help if we don't know the starting point. Curious, how is sql to xml conversion made -by SQL Server TSQL? Oracle PL/SQL? PostgreSQL XML fcts?